# "I need more info on this. What is the agenda of the meeting? What do we want to achieve from having this meeting?"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, email

I was invited to join a meeting and I needed more info about it. I also would like to know the agenda and the expected outcome from the meeting.

I replied the email with something like below

> I need more info on this. What is the agenda of the meeting? What do we want to achieve from having this meeting?

I know it sends the message that I wanted to send but it sounds repetitive especially I use the word **meeting** twice.

How can I phrase this differently so that it does not repeat the work meeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the meaning of “this” is clear, and you never need to say ”this meeting”, or it’s not, and you only need to use it the first time:

> I need more info on this [meeting]. What is the agenda, and what do we want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is also a pretty confrontational way to phrase the question, for the standard English-language office. The above message would probably only be appropriate for someone who you directly supervise (and even then might be considered rude).

I'd consider some 'softening' language -- for instance:

> Could you please provide some additional info about this meeting, so that I can be appropriately prepared? Is there an agenda or information on the meeting goals that you can share with me?